# How can Docker container write to a mounted directory with permissions granted through group membership?

Tags: docker, permissions, docker-volume

#### Versions

- Host OS: Debian 4.9.110
- Docker Version: 18.06.1-ce

#### Scenario

I have a directory where multiple users (`user-a` and `user-b`) have read/write access through a common group membership (`shared`), set up via `chown`:

```
/media/disk-a/shared/$ ls -la
drwxrwsr-x 4 user-a shared 4096 Oct  7 22:21 .
drwxrwxr-x 7 root   root   4096 Oct  1 19:58 ..
drwxrwsr-x 5 user-a shared 4096 Oct  7 22:10 folder-a
drwxrwsr-x 3 user-a shared 4096 Nov 10 22:10 folder-b
```

UIDs & GIDs are as following:

```
uid=1000(user-a) gid=1000(user-a) groups=1000(user-a),1003(shared)
uid=1002(user-b) gid=1002(user-b) groups=1002(user-b),1003(shared)
```

Relevant `/etc/group` looks like this:

```
shared:x:1003:user-a,user-b
```

When `su`ing into both users, files can be created as expected within the shared directory.

The shared directory is attached to a Docker container via mount binds to `/shared/`. The Docker container runs as `user-b` (using the `--user "1002:1002"` parameter)

```
$ ps aux | grep user-b
user-b     1347  0.2  1.2 1579548 45740 ?       Ssl  17:47   0:02 entrypoint.sh
```

`id` from within the container prints the following, to me okay-looking result:

```
I have no name!@7a5d2cc27491:/$ id
uid=1002 gid=1002
```

Also `ls -la` mirrors its host system equivalent perfectly:

```
I have no name!@7a5d2cc27491:/shared ls -la
total 16
drwxrwsr-x 4 1000 1003 4096 Oct  7 20:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct  8 07:58 ..
drwxrwsr-x 5 1000 1003 4096 Oct  7 20:10 folder-a
drwxrwsr-x 3 1000 1003 4096 Nov 10 20:10 folder-b
```

#### Problem

From within the container, I cannot write anything to the shared directory. For `touch test` I get the following i.e.:

```
I have no name!@7a5d2cc27491:/shared$ touch test
touch: cannot touch 'test': Permission denied
```

I can write to a directory which is *directly* owned by `user-b` (user & group) and mounted to the container... Simply the group membership seems somehow not to be respected at all.

I have looked into things like [user namespace remapping](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/) and things, but these seemed to be solutions for something not applying here. What do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container user has `gid=1002`, but is not member of group `shared` with `gid=1003`.

Additionally to `--user "1002:1002"` you need `--group-add 1003`.
Than the container user is allowed to access the shared folder with `gid=1003`.

`id` should show:

```
I have no name!@7a5d2cc27491:/$ id
uid=1002 gid=1002 groups=1003
```

Comment: Indeed! This solves my problem. Since I use docker-compose though, I had to set the docker-compose file version to "2" because revision 3 does not support group_add anymore. Thanks a lot @mviereck!

Comment: You're welcome! If you would need docker-compose 3 without group-add support, you can create custom `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`. As a quick'n'dirty test you can share the files from host. Nice side effect: your container user will have a name.

Comment: I don't know a lot about the mounting operations, but seems that if you change mounting options in fstab, for example, you have to force the OS to recognize the changes. "mount -a" doesn't do it for me. You can use "systemctl daemon-reload" to get the system to see the changes. However it doesn't work in WSL since WSL uses init instead of systemctl. I had to kill wsl ("wsl --shutdown") and start it up again. Then had to restart docker to get it reconnected in WSL. A huge pain, but finally got the shared mount and group permissions all working.